# Find unique lines between two files

Tags: unique, text-processing, comm

I have two very large files (File 1 and File 2), File 1 has many rows and columns, I am pasting column 1 for sake of simplicity. I want to print only those lines which are unique to File 1.

**File 1:**

```
AT1G01010.1
AT1G01020_P1
AT1G01020_P2
AT1G01040.2
AT1G01040_P1
AT1G01046.1
AT1G01050_ID7
```

**File 2:**

```
AT1G01010
AT1G01046
AT1G01050
```

**Output:**

```
AT1G01020_P1
AT1G01020_P2
AT1G01040.2
AT1G01040_P1
```

I have tried `comm` command in Ubuntu but it didn't work as it checks for complete pattern. so when it tries to check `AT1G01010.1` with `AT1G01010` it doesn't show anything common.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
grep -Fvf file2 file1
```

This will print the lines which no whole or partially matched with the lines in file2.

Answer (score 0):

`grep` is the best answer.

With awk: uses non-alphanumeric characters as the field separator, remembers the contents of file 2 and if the first field of file1 has not been seen in file2, print that line.

```
gawk -F '[^[:alnum:]]' 'NR==FNR {f2[$1]; next} !($1 in f2)' file2 file1
```

Works with GNU awk.

Or `join`

```
join -v1 <(sed 's/^[[:alnum:]]\+/& &/' file1 | sort -k 1,1) <(sort file2) | cut -d " " -f 2-
```